# Moving console application into background at user's option

Tags: c#, background, console-application

I've seen a few solutions for the question in the title, but they all don't do what I want.

I have  `ch = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;` , if a user inputs 'y' I want the app to go into background. if user inputs 'n' the program continues like nothing happened. Is this possible? I did a lot of research but still couldn't find one that fits me.

Here is what i have till now:

```
char ch = '0';
Console.WriteLine("Enter Log File Destenation:");
string url = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Run In BackGround ? (Defaul Set to False)";
ch = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
if (ch == 'y')
{
    //Move To Background
}

    // continue with program
```

It's a bitcoin rate logger. it takes the bitrate from a websites title and logs it into a txt file which destination is set by user at the start of the program.
after the destination is set, it asks if it should run in the background or not.
either way the program enters a while(true) loop for log.

Comment: I think you can't do it...

Comment: Your best bet is probably going to be to turn the code you posted info a launcher application which invokes the application that runs in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method with the param HWND_BOTTOM

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out W32RECT lpRect);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct W32RECT
        {
            public int Left;
            public int Top;
            public int Right;
            public int Bottom;
        }

        public const uint HWND_BOTTOM = 1;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           IntPtr handle = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
           W32RECT rect;
           GetWindowRect(handle , out rect); //to get position and size of your console
           SetWindowPos(handle, IntPtr.Zero, rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Right - rect.Left, rect.Bottom - rect.Top, HWND_BOTTOM);//to set background position of your console with the same size and screen's position
        }
    }
}
```

Not tested but it will be working

Source : http://www.developpez.net/forums/d199635/environnements-developpement/delphi/setforegroundwindow-setbackgroundwindow/   (I can translate if you need)

Comment: Can you be more specific ? i didn't understand this method